# do I reward bounty if my question has not been answered satisfactualy

Tags: discussion

if I offer a bounty and my question has not been answered satsfactualy...what do I do? I have not found a good answer but if I let the bounty expire...isn't it lost for everyone?

how does this work

Comment: Can you link to the bountied question?

Comment: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/stream-windows-audio-over-the-network/3209#3209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Stack Overflow blog, [bounties are not tied to accepting answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

Basically, you're offering to toss someone some reputation in exchange for better exposure to the question, in hopes of getting it answered sooner or better.

And yes, the bounty will be lost for everyone if it is not awarded. I believe this is [to prevent gaming of the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70280/156003).

Comment: poo...thats a bummer